# Uniqueness of a solution of the system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

A friend asked me the following question several days ago, and we still do not have a solution.

Prove that the system of equations below has only the solution $(x, y, z)=(1, 1, 1)$.
$$
\begin{cases}
x+y^2+z^3=3\\
y+z^2+x^3=3\\
z+x^2+y^3=3
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: What rihkddd mentioned. I tried to manipulate it into an equation of the form $(y−x)^2A+(z−y)^2B+(x−z)^2C=0$ where $A,B,C$ are perfect squares, to show symmetry. I got $(y−x)A+(z−y)B+(x−z)C=0$, but that is not exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The question should be wrong since at least it can be checked by [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E3%3D3%2Cy%2Bz%5E2%2Bx%5E3%3D3%2Cz%2Bx%5E2%2By%5E3%3D3) that it has more than one group of solution (in fact it has $27$ groups of solution).

Comment: I forgot to mention that we are working with real solutions.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could find that x,y,z are symmetyical ,which means x,y,z have no difference with each other ,so x=y=z.you can solve this original equation by transform to x+x^2+x^3=3,so x =1,the so the only solution is (x,y,z)=(1,1,1).
I'm not native English spaker ,sorry for my bad English,hope you can understand what I mean.

Comment: Yes, under the hypothesis that $x=y=z$ you can easily show that the only solution is $x=y=z=1$. However, the true question is whether there're other, non-symmetrical solutions.